# chi-distribution table question

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Clarify the chi-distribution for me please. The task is 1.Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, X_{4}, X_{5}, X_{6}$ be independent standard normal random variables. Find
(a) $\mathrm{P}\left(X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}>1\right),
\mathrm{P}\left(X_{1}^{2}+X_{1}^{2}>1\right)$. Are they equal? Provide the intuition.
I am now looking only at $\mathrm{P}\left(X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}>1\right)$. how do i calculate it? i fugured that it is chi-distribution and i have to use the table for chi-distribution of $\mathrm{P}\left(X_{2}^{2}>1\right)$. The calculator says the answer is 0.6065, but i don't get how to find this in the table. there are no such values?? Where do i find it? Thank you.

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.  $X_1$ and $X_1$  are not independent.  So you might reasonably expect $X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}$ to have a distribution less spread out than $X_{1}^{2}+X_{1}^{2}$ and there is no reason to expect the two probabilities to be the same.

Comment: Most tables for the chi-square distribution for $\chi^2_k$ (not chi-distribution and not written $X^2_k$) give critical values, and are not suitable for answering this question.  Fortunately a $\chi^2_2$ distribution is also an exponential distribution with parameter $\frac12$  so the answer is $\mathrm{P}\left(X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}>1\right)= e^{-1/2} \approx 0.6065$.

Comment: That does not work for other degrees of freedom, so you need another method for $\mathrm{P}\left(X_{1}^{2}+X_{1}^{2}>1\right)$, but that is $\mathrm{P}\left(X_{1}^{2}>\frac12\right)$ which is $\mathrm{P}\left(X_{1}>\sqrt{\frac12}\right)+\mathrm{P}\left(X_{1}<-\sqrt{\frac12}\right)$ which you might be able to find from your table of the normal distribution (unless that too is only showing critical values)

Comment: @Henry thank you, I understood